# Plotting rows and columns of big data in an interpretable way

Tags: python, pandas

I have the attached data set and wanted to visualize it.

[part of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY0JZ.png)

For small data sets, the visualization looks nice like the attached

[nice plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNhfj.png)

but for large datasets, it is hard to interpret as attached too

[hard to interpret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue0Xn.png)

I used the following code to visualize it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plot = TMA_A_B_cells_surroundings_distance.plot.bar()
plot.set_xlabel("B cells", color='red')
plot.set_ylabel("Distance", color='red')
plot.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red') 
plot.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')

plt.title('Cell Cell distance', color='white')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))


fig.savefig(fname='TMA_A_Distance_reg021.png', 
bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

I tried to make it as a scatter plot but got errors. Could you help in making it a scatter plot or any other interpretable plot?

Answer (score 0):

I used histogram and it worked fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Even your "nice" plot is not interpretable as it is. See how your +.03 and your + .13 are the same color? I would separate the plots for each B cell if that is meaningful to you, or perhaps plot them as facets so that the color among them stay the same.